# Editted Virtual Host ServerName in httpd.conf but it seems it did not take effect

Tags: apache, ssh, centos, virtualhost, httpd.conf

> So I have 4 Virtual Host. I made the 3 Virtual Hosts 2 days ago and it
>   all works fine. When I made another Virtual Host the next day, it
>   won't load up the newly created Virtual Host. So I tried renaming the Server Name of my 1st Virtual
>   Host which is running.

I changed the ServerName and Alias of www.test1.biboglobal.com to hogehoge.com with still the directory of test1. Saved the file and restarted apache. But when I tried to browse hogehoge.com,it won't load the contents.

> I tried browsing the test1.biboglobal.com and it still worked. But
>   that Server Name does not exist anymore because I changed it to
>   hogehoge.com.

I've searched all about httpd.conf not taking changes but found no answer. I hope someone can help me.

I also tried removing all Virtual Hosts and restarted Apache. But still, it was able to browse test1, test2, test3.biboglobal.com. Although it only displayed the Apache Test Page, not the index.html inside their respective directory.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# NOTE: NameVirtualHost cannot be used without a port specifier
# (e.g. :80) if mod_ssl is being used, due to the nature of the
# SSL protocol.
#

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for requests without a known
# server name.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@hogehoge.com  //**This was supposed to be test1.biboglobal.com**
     DocumentRoot /var/www/test2.biboglobal.com/public_html
     ServerName www.hogehoge.com         //**This was supposed to be test1.biboglobal.com**
     ServerAlias hogehoge.com            //**This was supposed to be test1.biboglobal.com**
     ErrorLog /var/www/test1.biboglobal.com/error.log
#     CustomLog /var/www/test1.biboglobal.com/requests.log
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@test2.biboglobal.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/test2.biboglobal.com/public_html
     ServerName www.test2.biboglobal.com
     ServerAlias test2.biboglobal.com
     ErrorLog /var/www/test2.biboglobal.com/error.log
#     CustomLog /var/www/test2.biboglobal.com/requests.log
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@test3.biboglobal.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/test3.biboglobal.com/public_html
     ServerName www.test3.biboglobal.com
     ServerAlias test3.biboglobal.com
     ErrorLog /var/www/test3.biboglobal.com/error.log
#     CustomLog /var/www/test3.biboglobal.com/requests.log
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@test4.biboglobal.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/test4.biboglobal.com/public_html
     ServerName www.test4.biboglobal.com
     ServerAlias test4.biboglobal.com
     ErrorLog /var/www/test4.biboglobal.com/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/test4.biboglobal.com/requests.log common
</VirtualHost>
```